# Quiero ejecutar una función Javascript al cargar una vista parcial en un MVC

Tags: javascript, html, css, mvc

Tengo un problema y es que al entrar en una página quiero que dependiente del tipo de usuario (tengo una variable con el valor) que entre ocurran una serie de cosas como por ejemplo que el color del tipo de letra de los  sea distinto.

Si hay otra opción mejor que no sea usar Javacript no me importaría probarla. Estoy abierto a posibilidades.

Saludos.

Comment: podes usar la variable para darle una clase y con CSS le cambias el color

Comment: Hola, ¿qué variable tienes para el usuario? ¿de dónde viene? ¿Puedes revisar el texto de tu pregunta y añadir código? Tienes que explicarte lo mejor posible para que alguien pueda ayudarte.

Comment: No entiendo bien tu pregunta pero si puedes identificar a tus usuarios desde el servidor puedes mandar en los header variables y asignarlos en los metas names. <meta name="nombre" content="valor">. despues con javascritp recuperas la variable y modificas el dom. O directamente desde el servidor sirve los estilos y configuraciones que necesitas en tu cliente. Yo lo hago como te digo porque hago puras SPA. Que cambian de estados durante el uso que le da el usuario.

Comment: Podrias mirar por favor [ask]

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado una solución al problema.

Yo estaba intentando usar esto:

```html
<p onload="cargarConfiguracionRol(@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Rol))">
Contenido que quiero mostrar en la web
</p>
```

Usaba el onload en un elemento porque todo el código esta dentro del body y no me valía añadir el evento onload al body porque en verdad este no lo volvía a cargar.

Entonces he descubierto que con otro tipo de elementos si funciona el onLoad, como por ejemplo:

```html
<iframe onload="cargarConfiguracionRol(@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Rol))" hidden></iframe>
```

De esta forma consigo el efecto que quiero, que al insertar una nueva PartialView a mi Layout lanzo una función JS para realizar una serie de cambios a la web.

¡¡Gracias a todos los que habéis contestado!!

Comment: Excelente, ayudanos a editar tu pregunta para que esta informacion sea de ayuda a otros desarrolladores de la comunidad, revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta, saludos